# SQL Server 2017 STRING_AGG Order By

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017, string-agg

I'm using SQL Server 2017 Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-GDR) (KB4583456) - 14.0.2037.2 (X64)   Nov  2 2020 19:19:59   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0  (Build 19042: ).

I'm trying to sort the results of the STRING_AGG function.

This works fine

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(Category,', ') AS Result
FROM LegacyReviews_Categories
```

This gives me the error "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near '('."

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(Category,', ') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY Category ASC) AS Result
FROM LegacyReviews_Categories
```

Comment: Can you recreate your error in [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18)? Your syntax appears correct to me. I tested on a dataset of mine by swapping out the table and column information. Perhaps it is data or data type related?

Comment: Here is a working [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8bfa8c/2)

Comment: I can repro this on a database set to 2008 compatibility mode `100`. With `COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL` of `110` or later it works.

Comment: @MartinSmith, interesting! I would suspect the first query wouldn't work either though

Comment: The first query does work. It just throws the invalid syntax with `WITHIN GROUP`

Comment: Doesn't seem like this limitation is documented https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks

Comment: It must have something to do with the data itself. There are 50 category values so I'll try and figure out which one

Comment: @user3641053 - no it has nothing to do with the data. It has to do with the compatibility level your database is set to. Have a look at `SELECT name, compatibility_level FROM sys.databases`

Comment: No, you're right @MartinSmith. The compatibility level was set to 100 and after changing it works as expected.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: There might be reasons why it was on 2008 compat mode though. You should verify that changing it has no ill effects for you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can repro this on SQL Server 2019 build 15.0.4198.2 too.

It just requires the query to be run in the context of a database set to `COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL` of `100` (2008).

[image]

All other (later) compatibility levels work.

[The documentation states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#remarks)

> STRING_AGG is available in any compatibility level.

And doesn't mention this.

If you are unable to change the compatibility level of the database to something higher then possibly you will need to fall back to the old `XML PATH` method of concatenating ordered results.

Comment: Interesting, is this a parse time error? If you use the query hint it succeeds (but I don't have a proper 2017 instance to test, and certainly not one on RTM+GDR path). https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d289785f12392185c2716e71a8dca13d

Comment: @AaronBertrand - yes. Parse time. And repros on latest 2019 build too

Comment: I suspect this is because though `STRING_AGG` can be used in any compatibility, `WITHIN GROUP` cannot, as that was added in 2012 with `PERCENTILE_DISC` and `PERCENTILE_CONT`. Though I don't have a 2017 instance to test ideas on either.

Comment: @Larnu quite likely.  The issue reproduces on 2019 too so no need for 2017